# Flutter: SingleChildScrollView Bottom Overflow error

Tags: flutter

I have this `SingleChildScrollView` Widget to make `Column` scrollable. However, I get the overflow error. I looked up on Flutter site to find necessary input but the example is not even showing up on my screen. How can I make this widget scrollable?

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        width: 300,
        height: 500,
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              aa(),
              bb(),
              cc(),
              dd(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you paste here the exact error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to know constraints/sizes of these widgets `aa(), bb(), cc(), dd()` and also see `build()` method to better suggest you a solution.

But i think the issue is that you explicitly set height of AnimatedContainer to be 500 pixels, and children of these parent are taller than 500px and that's why you get overflow error. Try to not to set static heights like that. If you delete the height field i think AnimatedContainer will adjust to take such space that you won't get overflow error.